# Homebrew recompile from edited source code

Tags: homebrew, recompile

Is there a way to to recompile from an edited source code via homebrew?

I did a change on the source user.hpp of Boost which I now want to recompile Boost with. I tried `--build-from-source` and `--enable-bar` but neither works, saying that it is already installed. The only way I can recompile is by reinstall but that simply overwrites the source code I changed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First option**
Download the archive, edit the files, and zip the archive as homebrew does (same name and format).

If you kept the original folder structure created by Homebrew, you can put the modified archive in `~/Library/Caches/Homebrew` and then try `brew install -f`. (the -f is maybe not strictly necessary but it may be need for the SHA-1 mismatch.)

More info on [this blog](http://mygeekdaddy.net/2014/12/05/how-to-install-a-local-file-in-homebrew/).

**Second option**

Pulled out from the Homebrew wiki, install the package without homebrew and then link it with `brew`.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/foo/1.2 && make && make install && brew link foo
```

Comment: Not really working! I copied the unzipped the Boost bottle containing source code and did the change, I then moved the zip file out of the cache folder and instead put the unzipped folder in there. But now when I run install, it wants to download the bottle. If I put the bottle back in too then it would just unzip the bottle itself and overwrite the folder I had there.

Comment: Try to re-zipp the files exactly as if it was download by homebrew.

Comment: It's not allowing me, gives the following SHA mismatch error. Anyway to get them be the same? Error: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: fdfc204fc33ec79c99b9a74944c3e54bd78be4f7f15e260c0e2700a36dc7d3e5
Actual: 9e9cdeb960f97bb33034f4a333edac13811b57106484ab24825f0a5020b16815
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/boost-1.58.0.tar.bz2
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.

Comment: You can use the -f flag to force the install.

Comment: Ignore it. Got them to be similar. Now compiling.

Comment: FWIW, I had to `brew uninstall ...` (instead of `brew reinstall ...`, which caches brew installation flags I didn't want), then `brew install ...`, then copy the "expected" SHA that was output, then replace the old SHA in the formula (`brew edit <formula-name>` opens the relevant file), then `brew install ...` again (`brew install -f` did not appear to ignore the SHA mismatch in my case -- in fact, I don't think the `-f`/`--force` option even exists anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to add a patch to the homebrew formula (you can edit the formula using `brew edit <formula-name>`):
https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Formula-Cookbook.md#patches